# Comportamentos inesperados com operações básicas no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber o motivo dos comportamentos, a meu ver estranhos, do JavaScript em subtraçôes com números reais:

```js
1.74 - 1.7
// retorna: 0.040000000000000036
```

Explico melhor a questão: gostaria de saber o porquê desta característica e se existe alguma forma de fazer a operação já à evitando. Não pergunto como arredondar ou formatar o resultado.
Sou novo em JS e no Stack, favor não me apedrejar, obrigado.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, espero que não tenha se sentido apedrejado. A marcação de duplicata não é nada contra sua pergunta. A ideia desse recurso aqui é criar uma teia de conteúdos relacionados para ajudar as pessoas a encontrar as respostas. Leia os conteúdos linkados no box amarelo do topo, veja se resolvem sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Para nós parece tão fácil esse cálculo e o resultado exato de 0.4, mas em JavaScript, todos os números são números de ponto flutuante do padrão IEEE 754. Devido à natureza binária de sua codificação, alguns números decimais não podem ser representados com precisão perfeita. Isso é análogo como o exemplo da fração 1/3 que não pode ser representada com precisão com um número decimal com um número finito de dígitos. Quando atingir o limite do seu armazenamento, você precisará arredondar o último dígito para cima ou para baixo.

Seu primeiro pensamento pode ser tentar arredondar para a segunda casa decimal. Infelizmente, as funções de arredondamento internas do JavaScript são arredondadas apenas para o número inteiro mais próximo.
Porém para seu caso e semelhantes onde o valor desejado é inteiro mais próximo poderia ser utilizado sim e recomendo o toFixed(2)

```
resultado.toFixed(2);
```

Não recomendo, mas:
Ainda sem usar outro framework ou plugin para calculos, existe uma maneira um pouco mais precisa utilizando números apenas inteiros, como no exemplo seria multiplicar por 100 os valores então teria: 174 - 170, porém muda a perspectiva de representação do valor, onde os decimais percentem aos ultimos 2 digitos do próprio inteiro, ainda nesse cálculo se fizer o resultado / 100 obterá o resultado desejado: 0.4

Obs. Funcionou para esse caso e muitos outros.
Mas claro, isso não pode ser 100% garantido pois a divisão e multiplicações podem resultar em valores inexatos.